# Moreau Decomposition with Bregman Distance

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I am working with a non-Euclidean proximity operator defined by a Bregman distance function $D(\cdot, \cdot)$:
$$
\operatorname{prox}_f(x) = \operatorname*{argmin}_u \{ f(u) + D(u, x) \}
$$

Is anybody aware of a result similar to Moreau decomposition for such proximal operators?

The only thing I found is a paper by [Combettes et. al. - Moreau’s Decomposition in Banach Spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-013-0663-y) about such an extension of Moreau decomposition for Banach Spaces. But I am wondering if there is something simpler which is true for Hilbert spaces, since I don't need something as general as a Banach space.

Comment: Which paper by Combettes did you find?

Comment: This one: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-013-0663-y

Comment: Bauschke, Borwein, and Combettes have a pretty broad-reaching paper on the topic of Bregman proximity operators/D-resolvents (preprint: https://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/sicon2.pdf) but from a quick skimming of the paper, it doesn't look like they have a direct analogy for Moreau decomposition. The properties in this paper may be useful though! Of course, if $D(x,y)=\|x-y\|^2/2$ then standard Moreau decomposition yields $x=\textrm{prox}_{f}x+\textrm{prox}_{f^*}x$ where $f^*$ is the Fenchel-Legendre conjugate.